Why is it a struggle to zoom into smaller objects?
I just shrunk a few objects to their actual real-life size- two donuts and a countertop. The screen isn't frozen and everything else seems to work just fine. I can zoom in or pan around the large objects. But now I struggle to zoom in or pan around the small objects. What happened? Is there a way to fix this or avoid it in the future?

Given the accepted answer, I'm guessing this wasn't the issue, but I've found that the absolute size (that is, the size in "blender units" as opposed to "physical units") of objects can be problematic if it is very large or very small. It's possible to change the absolute size in Scene Properties ⇒ Units ⇒ Unit Scale.

Thank you for your comment! I'm totally new to this and I'm adding your comment to my notes.

I can think of a few possibilities: Possibly the origin of your small objects is not centered. Go to Object > Set Origin > Center of Mass. Or you are locked in Camera to View (which can cause zoom issues).
Press NumPad 0 to toggle in/out of the camera.
Or your navigation preferences are limited.
Go to Edit > Preferences > Navigation and try these settings:


You can zoom by holding Ctrl+MMB and drag. This is a more accurate way to zoom.

Thank you! I'll try that.
